# Iterating through rows in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `(68x2)` matrix named `shape` and I am trying to iterate through all the 68 rows by placing column 0 and column 1 of `shape` in array `B`. This is then multiplied by a `(3x3)` transformation matrix `A`. Then my intent was to create a single array (which is why I used `np.append`) but actually all I am getting are 68 singular 2 dimensional matrices and I do not know why.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

for row in shape:
    B = np.array([[row[0]],[row[1]],[1]])
    result = np.matmul(A,B)
    result = np.append(result[0], result[1], axis = 0)
    print(result)
```

Anyone know how I can fix my problem?

Comment: If you need to iterate through rows, collect the results in a list, and turn that into an array once at the end.  `np.append` is EVIL.

Comment: I created an empty list `result = []` and at the end I added `result.append(result)` is that what you meant because I'm getting: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate a new column onto your `shape` array and then multiply all your rows by the transform matrix at once using a single matrix multiplication.

```
result = (np.concatenate((shape, np.ones((68, 1))), axis=1) @ A)[:,:2]
```

It's possible you need to multiply by the transpose of the transformation matrix, `A.T`, rather than by `A` itself.

Comment: Thank you this worked wonders. For my case I did not need to use the transpose of A